# Где хранить временные файлы?

Tags: c#

Нужна временная папка для хранения и обработки файлов. Прочитал на msdn, что можно воспользоваться Path.GetTempPath(). Какие есть нюансы при таком решении? Есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Неудобство еще в том, что имя временной папки TEMP.

Comment: msdn [GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *Какие есть нюансы при таком решении?* Масса... например, если файлов гигабайты, а свободного места на диске не дофига, может случиться неудобность... А также следует учитывать, что путь берётся из переменных среды, с которыми пользователь в принципе имеет право сделать что угодно (за свой счёт, разумеется, но кого это останавливало?). Разумнее затребовать установку временной папки в настройках, а GetTempPath использовать как значение по умолчанию. *Неудобство еще в том, что имя временной папки TEMP* Почему, позвольте полюбопытствовать?

Comment: А зачем их хранить? В памяти не помещаются?

Comment: В этом как раз не неудобство, а самое что ни на есть удобство, т.к. по идее ОС занимается очисткой этой папки от лишних файлов. Иначе вы можете создавать временные файлы прямо в рабочей папке вашей программы, но тогда вы должны сами озаботится тем, чтоб ваша программа во время подчищала за собой ненужные файлы.

Comment: @Bulson, разве папка TEMP очищается автоматически? Свой мусор надо и там убирать самостоятельно...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я написал "по идее", т.к. не знаю как это точно происходит в современной винде, раньше было так, что при перезагрузке ОС автоматом все файлы удалялись из темповой папки. Сейчас не так, видимо есть некий порог размера этой папки, когда ОС начинает автоматическую очистку этой папки.

Comment: @Bulson, автоматически ничего не очищается, только вручную с помощью штатной утилиты "Очистка диска" или сторонних решений

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пр.клик по кнопке пуск-> Параметры -> Система -> слева пункт Хранилище -> внимательно читаем раздел "Контроль памяти".

Comment: @Bulson, вы предлагаете писать только под Win10? У меня вот на рабочем ПК стоит Win7 и ничего такого нету

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня нет под рукой Win7, но там аналогичная функциональность присутствовала..., хотя могу ошибаться, потому что не пользуюсь сабжем уже с 2014 года.

Answer (score 6):

Если официальная документация говорит использовать `Path.GetTempPath`, то я бы на вашем месте именно это и делал.

Вам для доступа в нормально отконфигурированной системе даны App Data (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`) для данных вашего приложения (за которые вы лично ответственны), и временный каталог (`Path.GetTempPath`). Временные данные нужно, понятно, хранить во временном каталоге.

Предупреждение: если вам нужны эти данные между запусками программы, то храните их в App Data, т. к. Temp может быть почищен в любой момент. Хуже того, Temp имеет право быть почищен *в процессе работы вашей программы*, поэтому открывайте временный файл с эксклюзивным доступом (`FileShare.Read` или вообще `FileShare.None`), и не закрывайте, пока он вам всё ещё нужен. Кроме того, поскольку Temp доступен всем, я бы на всякий случай не оставлял там важную информацию наподобие паролей пользователя или номера кредитки. (Впрочем, для обеспечения безопасности нужно довольно многое.)

Если пользователь каким-то образом «запортит» временный каталог, это не ваша забота. Покажите сообщение об ошибке и прекращайте работу. Вы не можете бороться с пользователем, разрушающим свою систему: он может, в конце-концов, просто удалить половину файлов .NET Framework, если захочет всё сломать.

Comment: `он может в конце-концов просто удалить половину файлов .NET Framework, если захочет всё сломать.`  - да такие есть , но можно-же воспользоваться продвинутыми средствами компиляция, результатом которых будет запускаемый файл не использующий .Net вовсе !

Comment: @DigitalCore: Ну вы же не сможете всё равно вкомпилировать _всё_. Зависимость хотя бы от kernel32.dll всё равно будет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать для этого `System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile`. При этом создается папка в `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\` (если указан флаг `IsolatedStorageScope.User`). Пример записи файлов на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile)